# Does Django's collectstatic command double the space used in production?

Tags: django, static-files, collectstatic

I understand that collectstatic command copies static-files found in different Django apps of the Django project to a defined single path so that webserver can easly serve files.

Here is what question me:

For example, I have many big static-files in several apps and I push my Django project to production. I run collectstatic. The static-files will be copied to project static folder. It means that the static-files are now in two different locations so use twice the storage isn't it?

I probably miss a point somewhere in the production deployment process because it doesn't feel right to me in term of storage space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it does, and this is intended behavior. How large your files are? Git itself (presuming you use it) is not well-suited to store large files, I would suggest offloading those files into external services like S3. If this is not an option, storage should not be a big issue nowadays - it's pretty cheap, I would worry more about bandwidth and deploy time to copy those assets.

P.S. You *could* move files instead of copying them with the custom collectstatic command, if that's worth the hassle for you. Extend the default `collectstatic.Command` and provide a new `copy_file` implementation.